# QGIS - How to difference twin geometries?

Tags: qgis

I have a layer in QGIS of which some entities share the same geometry.
As a result when I click on an entity, the result identification often shows several entities.

Is there a way to display the number of overlapping entities on the map ?

Comment: I might suggest looking into the [labeling symbiology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/label_tool.html). You could create a new feature and sum the amount of entries that fall within the same location and then display that sum value with the symbiology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a label that fetch and count identical geometries. Click the expression icon beside the label value box.

```
array_length(overlay_equals('New scratch layer',1))+1
```

Let's break it down:

`overlay_equals('New scratch layer',1)` : using the current geometry, look in the given layer for **other** geometries being identical. Return, in an array, the value 1 for each matching geometry.

`array_length()`: count how many identical geometries were found

`+1`: since `overlay_equals` ignores the current geometry, add 1 to count the source geometry.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Identify Features Icon and click on a geometry - it shows you how many features there are.

Another possibility is to create a label that counts the number of identical features using this expression:  `array_length(overlay_equals( @layer, $id))+1`

[image]